# JSP Page not rendering in SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

I have seen lot of same problem but My problem is not resolving with all those solutions. My JSP page is not rendering.

I have added all required jars like thymeleaf, tomcat, jstl to run the application but still getting error

Below is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class BookResource {

@GetMapping("/recommend")
    public List<String> recommend() {
        return bookrepo.BookDetail(bookname);

    }
@RequestMapping(value = "/recommendation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String recommend(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("recommendations", bookrepo.BookDetail(bookname));
        model.addAttribute("name", "Harsh");
        return "recommendation";

    }
}
```

After i Hit the URL I am getiing below error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue May 28 09:50:33 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "recommendation", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

The JSP Page I have created not rendering, I put my jsp page inside resources/templates and also at WEB-INF/jsp/.
And properties file is also updated

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springBootApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstSpringBootApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Redis Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GCP Dependencies -->

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin> 

            <!-- GCP plugin -->
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Structure .

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 2):

As per spring boot there are [Limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) when it comes to jsp's.

If packaging is not declared in pom.xml, spring boot by default considers it as jar.

To overcome these limitations we need to have the configuration made in the application to render jsp by placing the jsp's under src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp folder.

Sample Code: [Click Here](https://github.com/girishkkumar/spring-boot-2-jsp-jar-example/)

References:

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1

https://github.com/hengyunabc/spring-boot-fat-jar-jsp-sample

Comment: This arrangement is not supported by Spring Boot. There's no guarantee that it will work today and no guarantee that it won't stop working in the future. If you want to use JSPs, the only safe way to do so is to package your application as a war file. Note that a war file can still be run using `java -jar` so you lose almost nothing by switching to war packaging.

Comment: In one of our project, we wanted the packaging to be **jar** instead of **war**. I tried to look for references in forums & blogs who else have faced the same problem and fixed it. Out of those references I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot [does not support JSPs when using jar packaging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations). If you want to use JSPs then you must use war packaging. You can do that by adding the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

It's typically placed immediately after the line with the `<version>` tag.

Having made that change, you should tell Eclipse to update your Maven project by right-clicking `FirstSpringBootApp` and then selecting `Maven` -> `Update Project…`.

Using war packaging will mean that `src/main/webapp` is recognised by Eclipse and your JSP files in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` should then be found. For further reference, Spring Boot has a [sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/d21a0912624e74d2d77e74ea30674bbe1e719b4f/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) for JSPs that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

***In 2021 version***, You need to add only `tomcat jasper`
dependency in pom.xml file to run the .jsp file in Spring boot application. Don't add jstl dependency, not highly required.

In application.properties file, you are required to add below code

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/folder name/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

actually this is not required

> ```
> spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
> spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
> ```

because anyways tomcat server locate the jsp file.

**It worked for me. 100% will work.**

Answer (score -1):

From your stacktrace it can be seen that springboot fails to resolve your template **"recommendation"**, so it must have something to do with where you have kept your jsp files.

Keep your jsp templates under `/WEB-INF/jsp/` since that's what you have provided in the `application.properties`. Also , ensure that the extension for your template is `.jsp` itself since you have specified that in property file as well.

Ensure that , in your pom you have the following dependencies added :

```
<!-- JSTL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- To compile JSP files -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can remove the thymeleaf dependency since you are using jsp as the templating engine here.

If that **did not work**, then you can try manually configuring your jsp view resolver like :

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Comment: The jsp file is in /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder and I didn't create any yml file, i have created application.properties under /resources/ file with prefix and suffix and both dependecies are in my pom

Comment: Okay , yml is the same as property file in springboot

Comment: So do I need to create yml file also?

Comment: No you can use the property file itself

Comment: You do not need to specify view resolver in configuration class, if you are providing the keys in property file.The view resolver is exlpicitly set using a configuration class when you want to overide something, otherwise providing the keys in property file springboot will automatically configure everything for you

Comment: Removed view resolver and still getting the same problem

Comment: Can you share your directory structure and your pom and configuration class as well ?

Comment: added pom and structure

Comment: Your webapp folder should be in the same package as your main Application.java class, so that springboot will take it up.Is it like that ? why is it like a separate package in your project structure that you shared. try moving webapps into the same package under main where main java class is present

Comment: You mean Web App as asource folder

Comment: Move your .jsp files under src/main/webapp but keep webapp under the same directory as your main application.java .

Comment: You almost never want to use `@EnableWebMvc` in a Spring Boot application has it completely disables the auto-configuration of Spring MVC. The manual view resolver configuration is also unnecessary as Spring Boot will do that for you and provides properties that can be used to customise it. The question already mentions these properties so configuring it manually in this manner is adding complexity for no benefit.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thank you andy for pointing it out to me, it was a miss from my part .Have updated the code accordingly