# I'm trying to add a jsp page in my Spring Boot Aplication. My problem is that every time I try to go to that page I have this:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Apr 26 16:10:15 IRDT 2022
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> JSP file [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp] not found

I have added the prefix and suffix into my application.properties:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

This is my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(){
    return "home";
}
}
```

and i have 1 warning in controller class :

```
Cannot resolve MVC view 'home'
```

[my project folders picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMZlK.jpg)

My Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OnlineShopApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(OnlineShopApplication.class, args);
}}
```

And the home.jsp:

```
<h1> hello world from jsp</h1>
```

pom.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.13</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>largesize.shop.app</groupId>
<artifactId>OnlineShop</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>OnlineShop</name>
<description>Online shopping web application</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: A sidenote: remove from your pom.xml all specific versions of `spring-boot-*` dependencies and maven plugins, and only keep the parent pom version at the latest available (`2.6.7` as of today). You are in for a dependency hell with pom.xml like the one right now.

Comment: could you post your folder structure and check if you have exported resource or static content in pom?

Comment: Tomcat 10 isn't supported. Also JSP only work with WAR files not with JAR files. You are also mixing Spring Boot 2.6.4 and 2.6.7 (don't mix modules from different versions of a framework, that is trouble waiting to happen).

Comment: Are you using thymeleaf? Also do you have the required templates like in your case `home`

Comment: @DavidKariuki yes, i added it and templates, but it did not work

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your file structure

Comment: What templates did you add, did you create those html files?

Comment: @DavidKariuki  hi, I attached the screenshots of the project folders
I found the problem: When I opened the project, I opened the folder that contained the project, which was one roll higher than the main project folder. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: I am glad I was of help, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are missing the template named `home`. You need to create this template and store it under `\src\main\resources\templates`
The template is a html file to which you are returning your response from spring to. It should be something like this:

```
project-directory
->src
    ->main
        ->java->com->...etc
        ->resources
            ->static
            ->templates
                home.html
                other_file.html
            application.properties
      
    ->test
```

Also stop using specific versions. Use this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also rollback to TomCat 9 as 10 is not supported.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

You can get these dependencies from [The MVN Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

to:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: I changed it but it didn't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This problem has been discussed here as well, and one of the solutions may work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334984/jsp-page-not-rendering-in-springboot-application

Answer (score 0):

When I opened the project, I opened the folder that contained the project, which was one roll higher than the main project folder.